# Abstract classes for immutable interfaces

Tags: c++, interface, abstract-class, virtual, immutability

Imagine defining an interface for representing natural numbers in C++. Ideally something like:

```
class Nat {
    public:
        Nat();
        virtual Nat next() = 0; // Bad
        virtual int toInt() = 0;
};
```

That would provide the ability to define various concrete realizations. The problem is that since `Nat` is abstract, the signature for `next` is invalid. Switching to a mutable version would work but that's not what I wish to accomplish. What is a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate on how two implementations of `next` could possibly be different?

Comment: Regardless, you won't want `next` to return a `Nat` or you will run into object slicing if you try to return a derived object.

Comment: Do you need run-time polymorphism?

Comment: @MarkB For instance one implementation wrapping an integer and another based on a recursive data structure. This is just an example to illustrate. What I'm really striving for is an immutable container interface.

Comment: @Cyber Yes, I understand the problem with returning Nat. I'm rather looking for a different approach. One that lets me program in terms of the general interface with the possibility of changing concrete implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Nat`s are immutable and that `next` is supposed to create a new object, I think the best approach here is to return a `std::unique_ptr<Nat>`, treating `next` very much like a factory create or clone method.

Comment: Will that handle all scenarios where, given `somekindofptr<Nat> it;` code wishes to perform `it = it->next()`, regardless of whether `it` holds the only reference to an unsharable object, the last reference to a sharable object, or one of many references to a sharable object?